# Check if user is service account

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, windows-users

I try to decide with use of host command below if a given username is service account or not.

```
Get-ADUser $username -Properties PasswordNeverExpires |
  where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq "true" } |
  where { $_.Enabled -eq "true"}
```

It should return only with one value, maybe with a True or False. How could I do this?

Comment: There is no inherent difference between accounts used for services and accounts used for interactive login.

Comment: This question should not have been down voted - it is legitimate and the user has provided the code they are using. We are here to help. I have up voted the question and provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the expression to a `[bool]` - if no user with those criteria exist it will be `$false`, otherwise `$true`:

```
$SAExists = [bool](Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -eq $username -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $true -and Enabled -eq $true})
```

Comment: Care to qualify the downvote with a comment, kind stranger?

Comment: Going out on a limb I would guess that the answer was downvoted because "Enabled and PasswordNeverExpires" is not equivalent to "is service account". Or, there is an SO Chaos Monkey randomly up- or downvoting questions and answers.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good point - I interpreted the question as "All SA's in our org can be identified by the fact that password never expires, how to determine whether SA with a given account name exists"

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe Mathias's answer is correct. To determine whether a given sAMAccountName is a service account see the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adserviceaccount?view=winserver2012-ps

The powershell command is:

```
Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity Service1
```

where 'Service1' is the sAMAccountName.

**Update:**

I have a similar posting to this question, but my goal was to get all managed service accounts through C# LDAP filter (see link below).

[Active Directory: How to determine whether account is service account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338380/active-directory-how-to-determine-whether-account-is-service-account)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/09/10/managed-service-accounts-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/

I hope this helps.